Access generically to computed property of an activated record
I am working on a Ruby on Rails application, rails version 4.2.1. And I am not familiar with subtleties of Ruby on Rails.
In some generic component of my application there is some code like that:
activated_record[property_name]

If I have for example an active record my_activated_record having an attribute name in database, we can read it by my_active_record.name but in the above component, if property_name is equal to 'name' this works also.
However, with a "computed property" defined as a method in the class:
def my_computed_property
   [some code]
end

this doesn't work the same: my_active_record.my_computed_property works well but in the above component, if property_names is equal to 'my_computed_property' this render only a nil value.
What can I do so that this generic component recognizes calculated value of an activated record like it recognizes database values?

Are you asking how to call a method dynamically? It can be done via Object#public_send or just send if you don't care about violating encapsulation.

Also this is a bit of a side note but Ruby doesn't actually have properties. It just has instance variables and methods. The bracket accessors (object[property]) is really just a method (:[]) that you can define in any object and your "computed property" is also just a method.

I would recommend not using the [] method to access "properties". I am also not sure how my_active_record['my_computed_property'] is returning nil in 4.2.1 since ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#[] should raise a ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError instead.

You need to show real code so we understand what you're trying to do. Most likely you're confusing Hash or Array accessors with something else. In addition, Rails 4.x is way past end-of-life, as is the version of Ruby is depends on, so it's hard to replicate a problem you aren't fully demonstrating with code examples.

Thanks @max, the method public_send do what I want!
